# What happens if you sequester a target which has a spell with a duration running on it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time

The Sequester spell (PHB p.274) states:

> If the target is a creature, it falls into a state of suspended animation. Time ceases to flow for it, and it doesn’t grow older.

If the target has spell effects with a duration in place is that duration suspended or does it continue to run down?

Answer (score 4):

**Spell durations are unaffected by a sequester cast on the same target.**

Spell Duration (PHB p.203):

> A spell's duration is the length of time the spell persists.

This has no stated dependency on the state of the target, including how time is flowing for it. It is an independent thing.

The sequester spell states (PHB p.274):

> it [the creature] falls into a state of suspended animation. Time ceases to flow for it, and it doesn’t grow older

Therefore time ceases to flow only for the targeted creature itself, not the environment it is in and, by implication, not for effects that are on it.

There is also the following clause:

> This spell also ends if the target takes any damage.

Which means a sequestered creature *can* take damage despite the ceasing of the flow of time, though this ends the spell which allows the damage to have an effect. Apart from that, however, time has ceased for the target and so you cannot change its state. Healing will not work, you can't put it in a silly pose. As the time ceases effect only applies to creatures not to objects, it would be a DM's call if you can strip a creature of all its belongings, in the same way certain spells don't work against objects that are carried or held.

Spell durations will run down, they will try to effect the creature and fail (e.g. healing will not work, telepathy will not work etc.) until the sequester ends.

It is clear that the "time ceases" part of the effect is clearly intended to allow a creature be sequestered for any length of time without dying of old age, but it is stated that "time ceases to flow" until the sequester ends due to a clause, a dispel or the target taking damage.

Don't bother sequestering a creature that is currently suffering from a spell or effect that has an overlapping duration and damages it during that duration, the sequester will end the next time the damage is applied.

As an aside sequestered objects (and plants) *are* effected by time passing, as it is only creatures that the "time ceases" effect applies. Iron will rust, food will rot, plants will grow.